# Firebase - know when data was saved to server after the app has been restarted

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Imagine a chat app (iOS + Swift), when I send a message, I first save it with state "Sending".
Now I want to change the state to "Sent" only after it arrived at the server.

How can I achieve this?

`setValue:withCompletionBlock:` won't work, because if I close the app while offline, the block won't be called when I open the app again.

Comment: Hello dear , You have store a status of your message. so you can retrieve status when app launch again.then use  setValue:withCompletionBlock: ......I know it is a very Tough solution but you don't have any way......

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, the message `state` is already stored by Firebase (with persistence enabled). Could you explain a little more?

Comment: can tell me which data structure you have use to store state of messages .i mean SQ-Lite or core data or etc.....

Comment: Please refer this link might be help you https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html

Comment: @HiteshSurani the docs don't show any example of watching when some data actually hits the server (considering you restart the app in the middle of the process). Like I said in my question, all I could find was `setValue:withCompletionBlock:` which doesn't work when you restart the app.

Comment: As for your first question, I use Firebase to store my messages (even offline), no SQLite or Core data.

Comment: The question says that the message is saved with state 'sending'. Saved where? Then you want to change the state from Sending to Sent. Where is that state stored? Can you provide a use case as it seems there may be a simpler way to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you know how Firebase works? It's stored in Firebase (server and offline sdk). It's saved with `setValue:withCompletionBlock:` and I want to change the state to Sent after the completion block arrives with success. If it fails (because I have no connection), I want to receive a callback when it's finally sent to server. With Firebase I just save the data and it worries about synchronizing with it's server. I'm not sure how to make it simpler, it's literally one method call, `setValue:withCompletionBlock:`

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz I faced the same problem. Now I don't find any good solution for this situation. Did you find?

Comment: @Alexsander Nope, most of my questions go unanswered =), I'm guessing no one knows, just like me.

Answer (score 0):

you can let the message model with a parameter named state and save it to local before sending to the server , when you open the app you can check messages with server

Comment: I'm not sure how that relates to Firebase. Do you know how Firebase works?